# Dell 926 printer keeps machine from booting

Tags: boot, usb, printer, dell-dimension

I've discovered that a Dell 926 printer, keeps my mom's Dimension 4200 from booting.  If the printer is plugged in via USB, then the machine will not even post.  As soon as I unplug the printer, the machine posts, and boots into Windows just fine.  I have a theory that it has something to do with the built in card reader on the printer, but I'm at a loss as to how to proceed with fixing this.  Is there something in the BIOS that I missed?

Update:
The 4200 did not have a option to disable booting from the USB.  It is in the boot order list and cannot be removed.  The problem has been resolved with a new HP printer, without the usb readers and pictbridge.  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 3):

It does sound like it might be trying to boot from the card reader.  Have you specified a boot priority in the bios.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the first thins I did.  That's why I was wondering if I missed something else in the bios settings that could cause this.  I'll double check it again the next time I'm at her house.

Comment: See if you can throw USB booting from your startup entirely. I have the same problem with USB devices on another computer here.

Comment: Look for "enable legacy USB"

Comment: I might as well try to boot from the built in memory in the printer. When I worked at Dell this was a fairly common issue but I can't remember the exact solution. disabling usb boot should work though